# What does "bar against"mean?

Tags: meaning

Administrative court complaints are however **barred against** decisions
[administrative acts] whose subject- matter is that of internal or external security of
the State … as well as other matters of foreign affairs. The decision of the [Federal
Ministry to refuse Nada’s request for the removal of his name from the administrative
act freezing assets] refers to measures for the implementation of international
sanctions and belongs thus to those decisions dealing with matters of foreign
affairs for which the Federal Council [the Executive] has in principle [exclusive]
competence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "barred against" is a structure here.
I think the text is saying that
"Administrative court complaints against decisions whose subject matter is xxx are barred."